# Loading Azure Text to Speech output to Azure Blob

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, text-to-speech

I need some guidance. My Azure function (written in node.js) will convert some random text to speech and then upload the speech output to a Blob. I will like to do so without using an intermediate local file. BlockBLobClient.upload method requires a Blob, string, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView or a function which returns a new Readable stream, and also the content length. I am not able to get these from the RequestPromise object returned by call to TTS (As of now I am using request-promise to call TTS). Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Adding a code sample that can be tested as "node TTSSample.js"
Sample code is based on

1. Azure Blob stream related code shared at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-js-storage-blob-stream-nodejs/blob/master/v12/routes/index.js
2. Azure Text to speech sample code at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS/tree/master/Samples-Http/NodeJS
3. Replace appropriate keys and parameters in the enclosed settings.js
4. I am using node.js runtime v12.18.3
5. Input text and the output blob name are hard coded in this code sample.

   ```
   // TTSSample.js
   // TTSSample.js
   // Converts given text to Audio and uploads to Azure Blob storage
   // Ultimately to be used in an Azure function
   // As of now input text as well as the target BLobStorage object are hard coded.

   // To install dependencies, run: npm install
   const xmlbuilder = require('xmlbuilder');
   // request-promise has a dependency on request
   const rp = require('request-promise');
   const fs = require('fs');
   const readline = require('readline-sync');
   const settings = require('./settings.js');

   const multer = require('multer');
   const inMemoryStorage = multer.memoryStorage();
   const uploadStrategy = multer({ storage: inMemoryStorage }).single('image');
   const getStream = require('into-stream');

   const ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
   const uploadOptions = { bufferSize: 4 * ONE_MEGABYTE, maxBuffers: 20 };
   const ONE_MINUTE = 60 * 1000;
   // Blob Storage
   const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');

   // Gets an access token.
   function getAccessToken(subscriptionKey) {
           let options = {
                   method: 'POST',
                   uri: settings.issueTokenUri,
                   headers: {
                           'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey
                   }
           }
           return rp(options);
   }

   // Converts text to speech using the input from readline.
   function textToSpeech_rp(accessToken, text) {
           // Create the SSML request.
           let xml_body = xmlbuilder.create('speak')
                   .att('version', '1.0')
                   .att('xml:lang', 'en-us')
                   .ele('voice')
                   .att('xml:lang', 'en-us')
                   .att('name', 'en-US-Guy24kRUS') // Short name for 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, Guy24KRUS)'
                   .txt(text)
                   .end();
           // Convert the XML into a string to send in the TTS request.
           let body = xml_body.toString();
           //console.log("xml string is done");
           let options = {
                   method: 'POST',
                   baseUrl: settings.cognitiveUri,
                   url: 'cognitiveservices/v1',
                   headers: {
                           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken, 
                           'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                           'User-Agent': settings.cognitiveResource,
                           'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat': 'riff-24khz-16bit-mono-pcm',
                           'Content-Type': 'application/ssml+xml'
                   },
                   body: body
           }
           console.log(options);
           let request = rp(options)
                   .on('response', async (response) =>  {
                           if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                                   console.log("Inside response");
                                   const stream = getStream(response);

        //request.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('TTSOutput.wav'));

                                   const AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = settings.storageConnectionString;
                                   const storageAccount = settings.storageAccount;
                                   const storageKey = settings.storageKey;
                                   const containerName = settings.audioContainer;
                                   // Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
                                   const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);

                                   // Get a reference to a container
                                   const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

                                   // Create a unique name for the blob
                                   //const blobName = id + '.mp3';
                                   const blobName = 'audio1.mp3';

                                   // Get a block blob client
                                   const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
                                   //blockBlobClient.upload(buffer,61000);
                                   //blockBlobClient.upload(request.body);
                                   try {
                                            await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(stream,
                                             uploadOptions.bufferSize, uploadOptions.maxBuffers,
                                             { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: "audio/mpeg3" } });
                                           //res.render('success', { message: 'File uploaded to Azure Blob storage.' });
                                           console.log('Success');
                                     } catch (err) {
                                           //res.render('error', { message: err.message });
                                           console.log("Failure", err.stack);
                                     }
                                   console.log("I am done");
                           }
                   });
           return request;

   };

   // Use async and await to get the token before attempting
   // to convert text to speech.
   async function main() {
           const subscriptionKey = settings.subscriptionKey; //process.env.SPEECH_SERVICE_KEY;
           if (!subscriptionKey) {
                   throw new Error('Environment variable for your subscription key is not set.')
           };
           // Prompts the user to input text.
           //const text = readline.question('What would you like to convert to speech? ');
           const text = "Hello there";
           try {
                   const accessToken = await getAccessToken(subscriptionKey);
                   //console.log("Access Token is done");
                   await textToSpeech_rp(accessToken, text);
           } catch (err) {
                   console.log(`Something went wrong: ${err}`);
                   console.log(err.stack);
           }
   }

   // Run the application
   main()




    //============ Settings.js

   (function() {
   "use strict";
   module.exports = {  
   // Replace with your own subscription key, service region (e.g., "westus"),
   // and recognition language.
   subscriptionKey:   "CognitiveServiceSubsctiptionKey",
   serviceRegion:     "eastus", // e.g., "westus"
   language:          "en-US",
   issueTokenUri:     'https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken',
   cognitiveUri: 'https://eastus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/',
   cognitiveResource: 'CognitiveResourceName',

   // Storage
   storageAccount: "StorageAccount",
   storageKey: "sN/StorageKey==",
   storageConnectionString: "StorageConnectionString",
   audioContainer: "AudioContainer",
   };
   }());
   ```

Comment: Please show us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), add your code.

Comment: I have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
const xmlbuilder = require("xmlbuilder");
const rp = require("request-promise");
const azure = require("azure-storage");
const subscriptionKey = "<your speech service subscription key>";

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  context.log("JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
  try {
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken(subscriptionKey);

    const blobService = azure.createBlobService(
      "<connection string>",
    );
    const writableStream = blobService.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob(
      "test",
      "test.mp3",
      {
        blockIdPrefix: "block",
        contentSettings: {
          contentType: "audio/mpeg",
        },
      },
    );

    const text = "Hi";
    const data = await textToSpeech(accessToken, text, writableStream);

    context.res = { body: data };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Something went wrong: ${err}`);
    context.res = {
      status: 500,
      body: err,
    };
  }
};

function getAccessToken(subscriptionKey) {
  let options = {
    method: "POST",
    uri:
      "https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken",
    headers: {
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscriptionKey,
    },
  };
  return rp(options);
}

// Converts text to speech using the input from readline.
function textToSpeech(accessToken, text, writableStream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let xml_body = xmlbuilder
        .create("speak")
        .att("version", "1.0")
        .att("xml:lang", "en-us")
        .ele("voice")
        .att("xml:lang", "en-us")
        .att("name", "en-US-Guy24kRUS")
        .txt(text)
        .end();
      // Convert the XML into a string to send in the TTS request.
      let body = xml_body.toString();

      let options = {
        method: "POST",
        baseUrl: "https://southeastasia.tts.speech.microsoft.com/",
        url: "cognitiveservices/v1",
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
          "cache-control": "no-cache",
          "User-Agent": "YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME",
          "X-Microsoft-OutputFormat": "audio-16khz-64kbitrate-mono-mp3",
          "Content-Type": "application/ssml+xml",
        },
        body: body,
      };

      rp(options)
        .pipe(writableStream)
        .on("finish", () => {
          resolve("done");
        });
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

[image]